# Is there an internal alternative to gist.github.com to run behind a firewall?

Tags: git, github, pastebin, gist

gist.github.com is incredibly handy, but I'd like to be able run something similar for sharing code samples internally with other developers behind the firewall where I work, so I don't constantly need to be sanitising my code all the time, just to talk about code examples.

Does anything like this exist?

I'm not after big project management tools, just a way to make throwaway gists, and share links easily, that also happen to be git repos, just like gist.github.com

Comment: Gist has a "private" post type where it's not public and has a long hash for the url so that it's not brute-forcable. Is that not enough?

Comment: Not really. I'm interested in only making it visible behind a firewall, and storing the data on our own hardware if possible - we're currently using an internal version of etherpad at present for some of this, but syntax highlighting, git integration, and easy link sharing are just sorely missed from gist.github.com

Comment: From what I can tell, GithubFI doesn't have a gist feature. I could be wrong.

Comment: gitpaste is probably the best out there and most up to date. It runs Django. I am using it now with Apache httpd and have modified it to connect to my company's AD along with securing it with SSL. It's very easy to customize.

Comment: @Daenyth: Many companies want to protect IP. Private links don't protect IP because now it's on GitHub's servers.

Answer (score 9):

You may check pastgit: git backed paste server (gist python clone)

https://github.com/mmikulicic/pastgit

Also gitpaste: (another gist clone based on Django)

https://github.com/justinvh/gitpaste

Answer (score 7):

Self-hosted, git-based pastebin in PHP: https://github.com/cweiske/phorkie

Answer (score 4):

The killer feature of github's gists in my opinion is their Git integration. You can clone your gists, version control them etc.

If you need just need something to collaborate, you can choose one of the [open source pastebins](http://web.archive.org/web/20111205120332/http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_pastebins) and make an install locally inside your intranet. One that comes to mind is [dpaste](http://dpaste.org/).