# Is there a tool that lets you access code snippets from the command line?

Tags: shell, command-line, code-snippets

I found this fantastic [command line tool](https://zachholman.com/boom/) that lets you store text. The text is added to a json file and you retrieve each one from the command line, fantastic. But there is no way to add code snippets. Is there anything like this for code snippets.

Comment: Do you mean CLI code snippets or arbitrary language snippets?

Comment: Sounds like GitHub gists, plus one of the many command-line tools for manipulating them.

Comment: @tripleee yes! is there something like that just for my computer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an internal alternative to gist.github.com to run behind a firewall?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924752/is-there-an-internal-alternative-to-gist-github-com-to-run-behind-a-firewall)

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Komandi](https://komandi.app) (a multiplatform command snippets manager) may help you.